# Why is failed input validation returning me to the start of my program?

Tags: c++, validation, input

Really sorry if this is a dumb question. I know it must have a super easy solution but I've been staring at this for so long I can't see it. It doesn't help that I'm really new at this either.

Long story short for some reason entering an invalid input past the first time returns me back to my menu, and sometimes also asks me to enter weight immediately after instead of allowing me to enter a menu choice. It's just all around broken and I don't know why. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

bool loopFlag = true;
bool loopFlagTwo = true;
int choice = 0;
int time = 0;
float weightPounds = 0;
float weight = 0;
const int BIKING = 8;
const int RUNNING = 10;
const int LIFTING = 3;
const float YOGA = 2.5;

int main()
{
cout << "Welcome to my Fitness Center" << endl;

do
{
    cout << "\n\t____________________________________________________________" << endl;
    cout << "\n\t\t\tMy Fitness Center" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\tActivity System" << endl;
    cout << "\t____________________________________________________________" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t Main Menu\n" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t1) Stationary Bike" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t2) Treadmill" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t3) Weight Lifting" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t4) Hatha Yoga" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t5) End" << endl;
    cout << "\t____________________________________________________________" << endl;
    cout << "\n\nEnter the workout that you wish to track, or end to exit:" << endl;

    do
    {
        cin >> choice;
        if (cin.fail() || choice > 5 || choice < 1)
        {
            cout << "Invalid choice. Please choose from option 1 through 5." << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
        }
        else if (choice == 5)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            loopFlag = false;
        }
    }
    while (loopFlag);

    do
    {
        cout << "\nPlease enter your weight in pounds: " << endl;
        cin >> weightPounds;

        if (cin.fail() || weightPounds <= 0)
        {
            cout << "Invalid weight entry!" << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
        }
        else
        {
            loopFlag = false;
        }
    }
    while (loopFlag);

    weight = weightPounds / 2.2;
    cout << "\nYour weight is: \n" << fixed << setprecision(1) << weight << " kilograms." << endl;

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        do
        {
            cout << "For how many minutes did you do this activity? " << endl;
            cin >> time;

            if (cin.fail() || time <= 0)
            {
                cout << "Invalid time entry!" << endl;
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
            }
            else
            {
                loopFlag = false;
            }
        }
        while (loopFlag);
    }

}
while (choice != 5);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: @KISKE Oh my god thank you. I knew it would be something stupid.

Comment: If you know what the answer is, please post it. If its a simple typo or syntax issue, then this question can likely be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `loopFlag` to `true` before every `do...while()` you have, or use another flag, because after the first `do...while()`, `loopFlag` is always `false`.